# what's the meaning of php-fpm's catch_workers_output configure item?

Tags: php

Today when i search how to open php-fpm's error log.I found that a lot of articles say that users should turn on `catch_workers_output`.But this really confusing me after i read this configure's comment:

> catch_workers_output boolean
>
> Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, stdout and stderr will be redirected to /dev/null according to FastCGI specs.
>
> Default value: no.

And i tried it,the result is:no matter 'on' or 'off',this configure does not affect php's error log action.What decide the log action is the two: `log_errors` and `error_log`.

So,what's the function of `catch_workers_output`?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this @poettian?

Comment: @wedi No,I guess It's about errors of the php process but not errors of application.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a script you would like to run in the background, it can be helpful to finish the request before you continue processing, especially if your work will take a while. For example, running a large report.

In these cases, `fastcgi_finish_request()` will send a response to the user as if the script has finished. After running this function, any calls to `error_log()` will be redirected to `/dev/null` because your server is no longer intercepting error output.

`catch_workers_output` causes your script's output to be redirected to the main error log. Without this option, you would never get error reports for problems occurring after `fastcgi_finish_request`.

A closed bug report with more information can be found here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80628